# cannot get json values after parsing

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-5

This works (alert shows : value1,value2)

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            //url: '@Url.Action("GetCustomerInfo","CustomerInfo")', 
            url: "../CustomerInfo/GetCustomerInfo",  
            dataType: "JSON",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (customerInfoList) {
              alert(customerInfoList);
              }
        });
```

but not this (alert not shown- chrome debugger shows : Unexpected error occured!)

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            //url: '@Url.Action("GetCustomerInfo","CustomerInfo")', 
            url: "../CustomerInfo/GetCustomerInfo",  
            dataType: "JSON",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (customerInfoList) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(customerInfoList);
                alert(obj);
                     }
        });
```

this is used on on ASP.NET MVC project;In controller following snippet used

```
List<string> customerInfoList = new List<string>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerId))
        {
            customerInfoList = customerInfoRepo.GetCustomerInfo(customerId);
        }

        return Json(customerInfoList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

whats wrong?

UPDATE:
i need to set customer Id and name from that list to a table in the cshtml - because i did the following to fill the list before sending list to the view.

```
using (dbContext)
                {

                    var customerInfo = (from c in dbContext.Customers
                                        where c.CustomerID == customerId
                        select c).ToList();

                    foreach (var x in customerInfo)
                    {
                        customerInfoList.Add(x.CustomerID);
                        customerInfoList.Add(x.Name);
                    }

                    return customerInfoList;
                }
```

Comment: Why would you call JSON.Parse() anyway? You're already specifying the return type in the dataType object.

Comment: @heymega please check my UPDATE thats all i needed! i tried to get the model and set the values.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, nice question but the answer is obvious.
alerting `obj` only provides something like [object Object]. Simply do something like `alert(obj.something)` where something is a key in the json.

Eg:

```
var text = '{"name":"John Johnson","street":"Oslo West 16","phone":"555 1234567"}'

var obj = JSON.parse(text);
alert(obj.name);
```

Which alerts John Johnson, but if you do `alert(obj)` it will only return `[object Object]`
Hope this helps

As of now, it is not clear where the error is from, but I suspect it be from the JSON script.
"json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)

See: [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: He's not hitting the alert. The error is thrown before then.

Comment: If then the alert is not being hit, the the error is from the JSON script. Something might be wrong in the script.

Comment: @heymega yes its "Uncaught SyntaxError:Unexpected number" in chrome before hitting alert

Comment: @Delali i tried alert(obj.something) but key must be either 'CustomerID' or 'Name'..isn't it? those are not available for that obj. like alert(obj.name);

Comment: Can you please give a sample of the JSON script. If you say those are not available for that obj, then you have to find the appropriate keys. Maybe a sample JSON script could help

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, you are using `JSON.parse()` to parse data which is already a JSON format (as returned by your controller action method). `JSON.parse()` is used to parse a string as JSON. To demonstrate, enter the following in your browser console

```
var data = '{"name": "John"}'; // data is a string!
data = JSON.parse(data); // data is now JSON (a javascript object)
alert(data.name); // alerts John
data = JSON.parse(data) // throws Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
```